# ODBC não oferece suporte para leitura de arquivo DBF?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Eu estou tentando fazer a leitura de um arquivo `.dbf` seguindo um tutorial que vi no site do Macoratti (obs. acho que todos conhecem). E ao executar o método logo abaixo, é lançada uma `OdbcException` com a seguinte mensagem: `ERROR [IM001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] O driver não oferece suporte para esta função`

```
        private DataTable lerDbf(string filename)
        {
            using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" +
                                         System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(filename).Replace(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename), "") + ";Exclusive=No"))
            {
                string consulta = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename) + "]";
                OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(consulta, conn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
```

Referente ao tutorial e aos arquivos, no site ele diz:

> [...] basta selecionar o arquivo FoxPro padrão Dbase e importar...

Os arquivos `.dbf` que tenho que ler no sistema é gerado a partir de um `.xls`. Seria este o problema? O que acontece? Há algo no código, talvez na string de conexão que esteja errado?

Comment: Você poderia linkar o tutorial. Eu vi um outro no mesmo site que não fala em FoxPro, e tem exemplos para ODBC e OleDB. http://www.macoratti.net/08/08/net_dbf1.htm. Eu não sei de detalhes destes drivers mas realmente pode ser que o driver não consiga fazer todas operações que o ADO.Net requer. Aí você teria que limitar o que usar. Se tiver muitas complicações, seria interessante avaliar a possibilidade de fazer importação dos dados do `dbf`, mesmo que tenha que fazer isto várias vezes ao dia de forma automatizada. Outra possibilidade é usar o `xls` direto e esquecer o `dbf`.

Comment: Não entendi o que você está fazendo aqui: `Replace(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename), "")`

Comment: @bigown aqui está o link http://www.macoratti.net/12/04/c_dbf1.htm

Comment: Tenta fazer o com outro que te passei e vê o que q acontece. Aqui tem uma referência para *connection strings* se ajudar para alguma coisa: http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/

Comment: Tinha achado esse site uma vez, muito bom. Ref. ao link que tu passou, tu sugere eu fazer com oledb ou odbc?

Comment: @bigown tinha achado um link do SO e acabei seguindo ele antes de verificar o link que tu me passou, funcinou perfeitamente! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356878/get-data-in-a-dbf-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: Eu tenho uma opinião diferente, até porque muita coisa lá tem problemas, mas ele tem várias coisas :) Eu sempre prefiro OleDB antes de ODBC, mas use o que funcionar. Eu nunca precisei acessar o `dbf` diretamente, só fiz importação, então só posso dar ideias.

Comment: Eu estava procurando no SO agora. Parabéns. Coloque como resposta e aceite-a então.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso o problema estava realmente na string de conexão. Nesta pergunta do SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356878/get-data-in-a-dbf-file-using-c-sharp - se encontra a forma correta.

```
string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourfilepath;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                var sql = "select * from " + fileName;
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                con.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
```